# Retrieving related models in Laravel 5.2 and update the same in Auth after login

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have created an UserController where i am manipulating user related information like login, logout, register and so on. I am able to login successfully and logout too. But i am not able to load other information from related table like profile, roles, address.

**Efforts and Code sample**

here is my code samples, please look and suggest me the solution.

```
User.php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Profile','user_id');
    }
}

Profile.php

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{
     protected $fillable = [
        'firstname', 'lastname',
    ];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function address()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Address','address_id');
    }
}


Configuration.php

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Configuration extends Model
{
    public function children() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Configuration','parent_id');
    }
    public function parent() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Configuration','parent_id');
    }
   public function address(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Address');
    }
}


Address.php

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Address extends Model
{
    public function profile(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Profile');
    }

    public function city() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Configuration', 'config_id');
    }

    public function state() {
      return $this->hasOne('App\Configuration', 'config_id');
    }

    public function country() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Configuration', 'config_id');
    }
}
```

All the above are my model below are the usercontroller code and view code:

```
UserController.php

.....

public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if ($this->auth->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
            $user = $this->auth->user()->load('profile');
            dd($user->profile()->firstname);      
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }

        return redirect('login')->withErrors([
            'email' => 'The email or the password is invalid. Please try again.',
        ]);
    }


.....

header.blade.php

@if (Auth::guest())

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
    @else
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                {{ Auth::user()->profile()->firstname }} <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    @endif
```

As, you can see, i want to print User First name from profile. But it is not in Auth. I also want to maintain role info from configuration table too.

Please suggest me the solution.

Thanks,

Comment: Once you have $user, you just reference the relationship properties like "$user->profile->firstname". If you use "$user->profile()" you're referencing the relationship itself, not the object pointed to by the relationship. Advice would be to play with "artisan tinker", and investigate how the relationships work and whether they work as you want them to. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships

Comment: As, you can see in the header.blade.php. I am trying the same thing but it is from Auth. I will access profile, configuration from any page that is why i want it to in the Auth. When i tried this, i am getting 500 error, telling me that firstname property does not exist.

Comment: Auth::user() will give you the current signed-in user, but in header.blade.php you're using "Auth::user()->profile()->firstname" and it should be "Auth::user()->profile->firstname"

Comment: Yes, you are right, but i am not able to do the same thing with address and configuration. Please help. if model relationship needs to be changed, please let me know.